# My Nuxt Button component does not have "href" attribute

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt and i have created Button component in a way that if we pass props`to`, it will generate `nuxt-link` and if we set it to `href`, it will generate `a` tag.

the problem i am facing is if we pass `to` it generates `a` tag but without `href` attribute.

> my Button.vue file

```vue
<template>
  <component :is="type" :to="to" :href="href" class="btn btn-primary">
    <slot/>
  </component>
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    href: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    to: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    type() {
      if (this.to) {
        return "nuxt-link";
      } else if (this.href) {
        return "a";
      } else {
        return "button";
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
   
<style scoped>
</style>
```

> my Layout file

```
<script>
import Btn from '~/components/Button/Button.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    Btn
  }
}
</script>

<template>
    <b-container>
      <Btn to="/about">I'm a Button</Btn>
    </b-container>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

Comment: It's because you're passing `href` to `nuxt-link` component.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Zuber just use a simple nuxt-link router component.

```
<nuxt-link class="btn btn-primary" to="/about">About</nuxt-link>
```

Hope its help.

Comment: This doesn't work. The OP is clearly rendering between nuxt-link and a depending on the link type, so using nuxt-link doesn't support that use case